# What does this Js snippet mean returning a freshly declared variable with undefined method

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm working on a legacy JS script :

```
!function(e, t) {
var a = function() {
        return new a.init
    },
......
//end of JS script 1800 lines later
a.init.prototype = a.prototype, e.PDC = a
}(window, jQuery);
```

i know that  ! is a way of declaring an IIFE, but the first variable declaration, i don't understand because the init method of variable a is not declared yet!

Comment: Did you omit a curly bracket? Two open but three close

Comment: i omitted the bracket, there are a bunch of functions defined inside,i hope there is enough for you to reason abou it the script is very big

Comment: Link to full script might help

Comment: it's a commercial script i cannot post it there sorry it's the PDC plugin for Magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of variables inside a function aren't looked up until the function is called.

Given `return new a.init`, it doesn't matter that `a` is `undefined` (it *is* declared) when the function is created, it will be before the function is **called**.